# Reflect re-sizing of hash table to main in C

Tags: c, hash

I have successfully created a new, larger hash table that re-hashes data from the current table and inserts it into a new one. However, it turns out that the change I want to make is being reflected locally, but not being passed back to main. At the bottom of the snippet below, I comment out the line `**listarray=**listarray2;` because I don't think that's what I want happening. I know the rest of the code is working as it should because in my insert() function, different array positions are storing the same values.

My only question: How can I get listarray2 to overwrite listarray, so that it is reflected back in main as my default table?

```
void resizeTable (node **listarray, int *size)
{
    //listarray is an array of node*, declared in main just like listarray2
    //size is 8, should reflect the change to 11 back in main

    int newSize= 11;
    node *temp; //iterating pointer

    node **listarray2= malloc (sizeof (node*) * newSize); //create space for a new array of node*'s

    for(i=0;i<newSize;i++)
        listarray2[i]=NULL; //set everything inside to NULL

    //go through original listarray (of size 8)
    for(i=0;i<(*size);i++) 
    {
        if (listarray[i]==NULL) //ignore empty array positions
            continue;

        temp=listarray[i]; //temp now points to a node that is not NULL

        while(temp!=NULL) //until the end of the list in that particular array
        {
            //arg1 is the new list,arg2 is the new Size 11, arg3 is the data from the to-be-old hash table
            insert(&*listarray2,newSize,temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    //free(listarray);
    //**listarray=**listarray2;


    *size = newSize;
}//end resize()
```

Comment: By emulating pass-by-reference, i.e. by passing a pointer. In your specific example, it should be a pointer to the pointer to the pointer to `node`, i.e. `node ***listarray`.

Comment: You need yet another level of indirection. Your current implementation copies the first node of thr new list to the first node of the old list. Pointers are not magic!

Comment: Joachim, are you sure you mean node ***listarray and not ***listarray2 ? I understand what you're trying to say, but implementation seems tricky still.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling `resizeTable`?

Comment: resize (&*listarray, &size);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming some of your variables for clarity, you would do this:

```
#include "assert.h"

void resizeTable (node ***p_listarray, int *p_size)
{
    //listarray is an array of node*, declared in main just like newListarray
    //size is 8, should reflect the change to 11 back in main
    node **newListarray;
    int newSize= 11;
    node **oldListarray;
    int oldSize;
    int i;

    assert(p_listarray != NULL);  /* From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h */
    assert(p_size != NULL); /* From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h */

    oldListarray = *p_listarray;
    oldSize = *p_size;

    newListarray = malloc (sizeof (node*) * newSize); //create space for a new array of node*'s

    for(i=0;i<newSize;i++)
        newListarray[i]=NULL; //set everything inside to NULL

    //go through original listarray (of size 8)
    for(i=0;i<oldSize;i++) 
    {
        node *temp; //iterating pointer

        if (oldListarray[i]==NULL) //ignore empty array positions
            continue;
        temp=oldListarray[i]; //temp now points to a node that is not NULL
        while(temp!=NULL) //until the end of the list in that particular array
        {
            //arg1 is the new list,arg2 is the new Size 11, arg3 is the data from the to-be-old hash table
            insert(&*newListarray,newSize,temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

    *p_listarray = newListarray;
    *p_size = newSize;

    free(oldListarray);
}//end resize()
```

And then call it like

```
    node **listarray;
    int size;

    // Initialize the hash table, and then when it needs resizing...
    resizeTable(&listarray, &size);
```

Comment: This is what the comment above meant by another level of indirection! I will study how this works, because it actually does!Thank you